# Problem in writing error logs to a file in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I'd like to do some error handling in my R program. So I'm using `tryCatch` function and I would like to write the error message (in case there is any error to a file). Here is the code I have

```
basicConfig(level='INFO')
addHandler(writeToFile, file=file_name.txt, level='INFO')

tryCatch(
{
  logger <- getLogger()
  ...
},

error=function(cond) {

  logger$error(cond)      
})
```

but it looks like `cond` does not contain the error message and the log file ends up as empty. How can I write down th error thread/message then?

Comment: Perhaps you jsut need `logger <- tryCatch(getLogger(), error = function(cond) print(e)) `?

Comment: what is 'e' here? where did you define it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that should be `cond`, not `e`. My apologies

Comment: so in my code, I'm writing cond to a file while you're printing it; the problem is cond ends up as empty and apparently does not capture the exception details